# Fixed Scroll Landing Page (Desktop only): Good or Bad?

Tags: scrolling, landing-page

Quick question - Are fixed scroll landing pages on desktop good or bad for user experience?

[Click here for a Fixed Scroll Landing Page Demo](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html)

I think it is good because it keeps the user focused on the page content since every element in each section fits nicely into the viewport.

Nonetheless, during UAT we have heard some negative feedback about the scrolling action being difficult to control.

I believe there are pros and cons to doing so and would like to hear your thoughts about this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my point of view there are some good and bad points about it

### Negative Points

**1)** Animation and movement grabs your eyes first rather than your content it might distract user

**2)** It is hijacking normal scrolling behavior so people might get confused

**3)** No clear affordance (Hints) that there is content below when the user is landed on the page

**4)** User might not scroll unless they see that this page have content below that is why most companies use 90% height for the first Hero/Featured area so the user sees the 10% of the next section

### Good Points

**1)** Less content to focus at a time

**2)** User attention is high on the content

**Suggestion:** I would not advise you to go with this if your main purpose is conversion and building trust of your users. Keep the top section of your Landing page about 90% the height of the browser window so user knows that there is some scrolling to do beyond this point...

Answer (score 0):

I don't like it, here's why:

- **you have to wait till the animation is finished**
  it's less responsive (nothing happens if you scroll during the animation)
  you can't quickly scroll up and down
  because of these it might seem bulky
- **missing consistency**
  the default scroll behavior is everywhere i.e. the user expects it
  if there is no scroll bar the user probably doesn't scroll at all

Answer (score 0):

I think Fixed Scroll Landing Pages are good for UX and Conversions as Users can see all the valuable Info which you want to show them and which they are looking for on Front fold without any hassle and delay.

In reference to the Demo LP:
It has clearly standing CTAs which is good, however users may not scroll down as it appears to be only one screen and other two screens and info on them will be missed out so you will have to guide them. You can use a simple arrow pointer pointing downwards for this.